# How to make dotnet globally accessible in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, .net-core

I've installed .NET Core SDK on Windows 10 machine using [dotnet-install scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) with the powershell command

```
./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel Current
```

SDK was installed to default location C:\Users\[*USERNAME*]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet and the only way I can use it from another location is

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

How to make it global to use just `dotnet` anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install it via scripts use key `-InstallDir` for change directory.
To use exe file from everywhere just change Environment variable (add path to exe).
For add it to your user PS profile:

```
Add-Content -Path $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts -Value '$Env:Path += ";C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\dotnet.exe"'
```

Comment: But will it help with global access? And I want the solution for already installed SDK

Comment: use this link to change [link](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: That worked, thank you! But the PS solution worked only for PS running under administrator. To make dotnet accessible also for PS under my user account I changed PATH for my user via GUI using the link in the comment. When I tried to do it using PS I got error: Add-Content : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\sur\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'

Answer (score 0):

To make dotnet globally, then you have to add directory where `dotnet.exe` is present to `PATH` environment variable.

Please keep in mind that default `-InstallDir` is `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\dotnet`, so it is located under user folder, and it would be not available for all users on the machine. To make a dotnet fully globally you should install it to directory which would be accessible for all users on given machine.

Answer (score 0):

The link by Vad helped. In my case, the `dotnet` folder was present in **both** locations aka `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` and `C:\Program Files\dotnet`.
So by pressing `Windows Key` and typing `env` to select `Edit the system environment variables`, then moving `x64` aka `Program Files` path up in GUI solved my problem:

[image]

Then checked by opening a new command prompt:

[image]